# netplan how to set hostname via option 12

Tags: dhcp, netplan, systemd-networkd

I run Ubuntu 20.04 based from the cloudimage...
so netplan has its 50-cloud-init.yaml which just says .. use dhcp

In the background it uses systemd-networkd as backoffice

But how can I advise ubuntu to set the hostname based on option 12?
In the past we used dhclient exit hooks but with netplan and systemd this doesn't work anymore.
So how can I do this ?

The UseHostname Option in Section DHCP in /etc/systemd/networkd.conf is not accepted (unknown option)

Comment: What is "option 12"? Have you looked at `/etc/hostname` and `man hostname`?

Comment: I also have been unable to force my own hostname (option 12) or override a shorter lease time for testiing purposes as was trivial with dhclient. Doesn't your option request belong in `/etc/systemd/network/10-wan.network` (your `10-wan.network` will be whatever for your network) instead of `/etc/systemd/networkd.conf`.

Comment: option 12 is a dhcp option to inform the client about the hostname to be assigned from dhcp server point of view
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dhcp/configuration/xe-3se/3850/dhcp-xe-3se-3850-book/dhcp-client-option-12.pdf

Comment: the different networkd conf doesnt help. Obviously ubuntu 20.04 doesnt know anything about UseHostname or SendHostname
'Oct 19 21:02:39 sql-new systemd-networkd[1926]: /etc/systemd/networkd.conf:21: Unknown key name 'UseHostname' in section 'DHCP', ignoring.
Oct 19 21:02:39 sql-new systemd-networkd[1926]: /etc/systemd/networkd.conf:22: Unknown key name 'SendHostname' in section 'DHCP', ignoring.'

Comment: According to `systemd.network(5)`, the `UseHostname` option is supposed to be set in a `DHCPV4` section, not a `DHCP` section.  However, this manpage also specifies that it describes the syntax of `.network` files - not of `/etc/systemd/networkd.conf`.  It does not appear to be possible to set `UseHostname` globally for networkd., you need to be able to modify a `.network` file to accomplish this.

Comment: but the transient hostname isnt a good solution at all. Usually this Option 12 should set the hostname like hostnamectl static

Answer (score 0):

As documented in `netplan(5)`, you can specify `use-hostname: true` as part of the `dhcp4-overrides` for an interface.